# Compiling and running Java code in Notepad++

Tags: java, compilation, notepad++

I got a new computer and I'm trying to get Notepad++ to run how it did on my old one. I got the NPPExec plugin. When I click Execute, it brings up the commands I want to enter. My goal here is to have the code save, compile, and run in the console of Notepad++. Currently I have what I thought used to work on my old laptop.

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)

javac $(FILE_NAME)

java $(NAME_PART)
```

Whenever I try and execute it though, I get

```
Current directory: C:\Directory
javac HelloWorld.java
; about to start a child process: "javac HelloWorld.java"
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.

java HelloWorld
; about to start a child process: "java HelloWorld"
CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've tried it on files I used to have, and just a basic Hello World

```
class HelloWorld
{
    Public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I don't get what the problem is, and would love if someone would be able to help.

Edit: I am using Windows

After checking here: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/first-java-program/ and seeing the Set Path section, I reinstalled Java, did the set path command, although the file path ended at \Java and did not have that whole JDK bit in it. I'm not sure if that's part of the issue and Java is not installed properly.

Edit 2: Tried to Find where I can install JDK, and everything sent me to Oracle's website. Is this needed?

Edit 3: Well, I tried just executing the javac command through command prompt and got

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I'm pretty sure it's the issue with JDK not being in the folder. I went to check my old laptop, and it didn't have JDK in the folder either. It gives the same error when using the javac command, but for some reason the java command works fine to execute the file. Do I really have to create an Oracle account just to get JDK? When I went to sign up it wanted my work phone number, so it definitely didn't seem like a free thing.

Edit 4: I tried following the [Oracle documentation on installing a jdk](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-BCE568C9-93D3-49F4-9B0C-9DD4A3419792). I did the download from there, but following that, I didn't see the file I needed. In the Java folder, there is now the jdk-16 folder. In the bin folder there, there are a number of .exe files, but I don't know if any of them are the ones I'm supposed to run. Now that I've installed it though, I'm still getting an error with javac command, but the java command will run files I'd previously compiled.

Comment: I think the message is that Notepad++ (or maybe the plugin) is saying it cannot find javac. That might be because the PATH environment variable does has not been set properly. Try an `echo %PATH%` command in a command window and see whether the correct Java folder is present.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I tried that, but I'm not exactly sure what the results are. I did the command in the NotePad++ console and it just responded with %PATH%. Is there more to the command that I should try? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Michael I'm really not trying to do any serious coding, just kind of playing around with some stuff. I'm just trying to get it to work how I'm used to it working so I don't have to go and learn something different.

Comment: Are you _sure_ the java file is in the correct directory? Also, try changing `class HelloWorld` to `public class HelloWorld` and `Public static void main(String args[])` to `public static void main(String args[])`

Comment: @CodingM I fixed the public typo, but it didn't change anything. HelloWorld was just an example, but I'm having the same issue with a file that worked fine on my old laptop. I'm not totally sure how to check the directory. I opened the folder where I have the files saved as a workspace. The cd command runs and lists the correct directory, it just runs into the issue at the javac command.

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, doing the `dir` command after you do `cd your_directory` will list the files inside the directory (or 'folder'), thus confirming if `HelloWorld.java` is really in that folder. Another possible solution is checking if you saved the file as HelloWorld.java and not HelloWorld.txt (Im just making sure the problem isn't a misplaced file, as the java code seems fine.)

Comment: @CodingM Yes it is saved as HelloWorld.java in that folder

Comment: The problem is that "it" cannot find the `javac` and `java` commands.  That will be nothing to do with the source file or where it is located.  It will be something to do with the command search path that "it" is using.  What happens when you run `javac -version` or `java -version` from a regular command prompt?

Comment: (I can't find decent documentation for NPPExec ... so I would be inclined to not use it.  Just use `javac` and `java` from the command prompt.  Or "graduate" to using a proper IDE.)

Comment: @Stephen C Using either command just gives "Not recognized as an internal or external command" when used from the Command Prompt. If I do switch to an IDE, what would you recommend?

Comment: OK so the explanation is either that a Java JDK is not installed at all OR you haven't add the Java JDK installation's `bin` directory to the `%PATH%` variable correctly.  That probably explains why NPPExec cannot find the commands either.

Comment: *"So I'm pretty sure it's the issue with jdk not being in the folder."* - Nope.  You don't need the JDK "in the folder".  You need to download and install a Java JDK, then you need the full pathname of the JDK's `bin` directory in the `%PATH%` variable.  This is basic Windows shell stuff.  (We cannot see exactly what you have done on your system, but you probably didn't follow the Oracle instructions properly.  "Close enough" is not good enough ... for stuff like this.)

Comment: *"Do I really have to create an Oracle account just to get jdk? When I went to sign up it wanted my work phone number, so it definitely didn't seem like a free thing."*  - If it says you do, then you do.  Oracle needs your details in case you violate the license ... and use Java for a purpose that is not covered by their "free use" exclusions.

Comment: Remember ... if a service / product is free .... >you< are the product :-)

Comment: @StephenC Fair enough. I'm trying to follow the oracle documentation on installation of a jdk now, but it seems outdated. I downloaded the jdk file and extracted it to the Java Folder, but it still doesn't seem to work. In the bin folder there are like 20 different .exe files, none of which seem to match the one named in the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-microsoft-windows-platforms.html#GUID-BCE568C9-93D3-49F4-9B0C-9DD4A3419792

Comment: You don't need to use Oracle's JDK, you can also use Java from other vendors, like AdoptOpenJDK/Adoptium, Azul, Red Hat (not sure if for Windows), Microsoft and others.

Comment: Your update #4 implies you're installing JDK 16, the instructions in your last comment are for JDK 11--it wouldn't surprise me if there were differences between five revs.